# Android NFC transaction flow

Tags: android

I am new for NFC . I want to understand it's flow of transaction. Is there any broad level diagram explaining how Android applications would use NFC for carrying out bank transactions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap, looks on the android developer guide (it's not exactly a diagram but it explain a lot) :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html